# Append drawing from one doc to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to create a function that copies all the content from one Google doc to another one. The template has tables, images, text and drawings The text and tables copy over just fine, but it's the drawings and pictures that don't seem to work. I've tried different things, but I always get errors.

This is what I have (I also got this from stackoverflow):

```
function copyTemplate() {

  var thisDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var thisBody = thisDoc.getBody();

  var templateDoc = DocumentApp.openById('LMwo6kT1_XDCh-8HkwTNN890W3_MeL6AJKU');
  var templateBody = templateDoc.getBody();

  for(var i=0; i<templateBody.getNumChildren();i++){
    switch (templateBody.getChild(i).getType()) { 

      case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH:
        thisBody.appendParagraph(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM:
        thisBody.appendListItem(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE:
        thisBody.appendTable(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_DRAWING:
        var drawing = element.asParagraph();
        thisBody.appendParagraph(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE:
        thisBody.appendImage(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm a newby so maybe the answer is super easy but I don't seem to find it. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Why not simply copy the file?

Comment: Because it's not the only template I have. There's at least 5. So the idea is the full code will be a repetition of this 5 times, each a different function copying from a different doc. Then I'll add a menu to the toolbar so that I can choose when to copy over from a doc, and even multiple times if needed. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
  case DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_DRAWING:
    thisBody.appendImage(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
    break;
  case DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE:
    thisBody.appendImage(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
    break;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying!
I get this error: Exception: Action not allowed :/

Comment: I created a test doc with an inline image and an inline drawing.  Actually the type is PARAGRAPH and it copies.  How are you inserting the drawing or image in the source?

Comment: With a menu in the toolbar linked to the function. Guess I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out why...