# Inline Drawings not Copying From One Google Doc to Another (Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I am trying to copy inline drawings from one document to another. I have been successful in copying text, tables, etc. but am having issues with inline drawings.

For additional context, the code is linked to a Google Form and copies certain pages to a new document based on the results of the submission.

The error message simply reads "Action not allowed" at the line "body.appendParagraph(drawing)". I own all of the source materials/code. The error message is emailed to me upon submission.

I have seen from other responses that the inline drawing element is a child of the paragraph element and have tried to use the suggested fix but for some reason, it is not working for me.

Relevant code is shown below. Please let me know if you need any additional information and I would be happy to provide it! I have little to no coding background so I am sure there is just a silly mistake somewhere.

```
if (question_two_answer != 'correct_answer') {
    var totalElements = otherBody2.getNumChildren();
      for( var k = 0; k < totalElements; ++k ) {
        var element = otherBody2.getChild(k).copy();
        var type = element.getType();
        if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ) {
          if(element.asParagraph().getNumChildren() !=0 && element.asParagraph().getChild(0).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_DRAWING) {
            var drawing = element.asParagraph().copy();
            body.appendParagraph(drawing);
          }
          else {
          body.appendParagraph(element);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

EDIT: FIXED ISSUE WITH WORKAROUND

So, I just took screenshots of every drawing and replaced the drawings in the document with the images instead. Then, this code worked for me:

```
if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ) {
      if(element.asParagraph().getNumChildren() !=0 && element.asParagraph().getChild(0).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
        var blob = element.asParagraph().getChild(0).asInlineImage().getBlob();
        var styles = {};
        styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
        var blobbody = body.appendImage(blob);
        blobbody.getParent().setAttributes(styles);
        //resizing the image
       var width = blobbody.getWidth();
       var newW = width;
       var height = blobbody.getHeight();
       var newH = height;
       var ratio = width/height;
       Logger.log('w='+width+'h='+height+' ratio='+ratio);
       if(width>480){ 
          //max width of image
          newW = 480; 
          newH = parseInt(newW/ratio);
       }
       blobbody.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH); //resizes the image
      }
      else {
      body.appendParagraph(element);
      }
    }
```

Kind of a pain to do this, especially with a large number of documents, but it works. Leaving this question up in case anyone can successfully fix this without a workaround later and so that my workaround may help others :)

Comment: "for( var k = 0; k < totalElements; ++k )" should read `for( var k = 0; k < totalElements; k++ )`. The problem is the increment of k.

Comment: Thanks for the input but this didn't fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Have you read/are you relying on the answer by @Tanaike in this question ? [Google Apps Scripts - Copy Inline Drawing from One Document to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358126/1330560)

Comment: Yes, in addition to the following source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75321460/append-drawing-from-one-doc-to-another

Comment: You might have read [Google Apps Scripts - Copy Inline Drawing from One Document to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358126/1330560) but **did you disable V8 runtime?** @Tanaike wrote: "When [...] script is used with V8 runtime, an error like Exception: Action not allowed occurs. [...] This has already been reported at Google issue tracker. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161999487)" I used your script and got the "Action not allowed" error BUT as soon as I disabled V8, the script worked and the inline drawings were copied from one document to another.

Comment: Yes I did haha. I even double-checked that I did and it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to copy inline drawings from one document to another but you get an error message "Action not allowed" at the line `body.appendParagraph(drawing)`.

Your code is based on [Google Apps Scripts - Copy Inline Drawing from One Document to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358126/1330560) and informed by [Append drawing from one doc to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75325275/1330560).

The error message is because of a bug in V8 runtime. To quote @Tanaike, "[...] when the paragraph including the inline drawings is copied, please disable V8 runtime. When the above-modified script is used with V8 runtime, an error like Exception: Action not allowed occurs."

The following code (based on the OP code) works perfectly.

---

**Working Code**

```
function copySource2Target() {
  var sourceDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var sourceBody = sourceDoc.getBody()

  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById('<<insert doc id>>');
  var targetBody = targetDoc.getBody()


  //if (question_two_answer != 'correct_answer') {
    var totalElements = sourceBody.getNumChildren();
      for( var k = 0; k < totalElements; ++k ) {
        var element = sourceBody.getChild(k).copy();
        var type = element.getType();
        if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ) {
          if(element.asParagraph().getNumChildren() !=0 && element.asParagraph().getChild(0).getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_DRAWING) {
            // Logger.log("DEBUG: k:"+k+", Type:"+type+", child type:"+ element.asParagraph().getChild(0).getType())
            var drawing = element.asParagraph().copy()
            targetBody.appendParagraph(drawing)
            // Logger.log("DEBUG: k:"+k+" - appended drawing")
          }
          else {
              // Logger.log("DEBUG: k:"+k+", Type:"+type)
              targetBody.appendParagraph(element.asParagraph().copy())
              // Logger.log("DEBUG: k:"+k+" - appended element")
          }
        }
      }
  //}
}
```

---

**Project settings**

[image: settings]

---

**Source**

[image: source]

---

**Target - BEFORE**

[image: target_before]

---

**Target - AFTER**

[image: target_after]